# BG not displaying when called

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a background image to be displayed on a div. But when called, it doesn't display. But when I call it on the entire body, the image is being displayed. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE> 
<html>
 <head> 
 <title>CSS image placement</title>
 <style>
#header{
    background-image: url('bg.jpg');
     background-size: cover;
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px;
     border: 0px;
    }
 </style>
 </head> 
 <body>
 <div id="header"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

****** EDIT ******

I'm adding the code that I edited and tried again with your help. Still no luck when I call the style on div.

```
<!DOCTYPE> 
<html>
 <head> 
 <title>CSS image placement</title>
 <style>
#header{
    background-image: url('bg.jpg');
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px;
     border: 0px;
     width:50px;
     heigth:50px;
}
 </style>
 </head> 
 <body>
 <div id="header" ></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: set `height` and `width` you will see the `background`

Comment: The header is a block level element and it does not have height or width mentioned. It does not have any content also. So it takes height and width 0 and does not show the background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your #header some height. It will work.

Try this -

```
#header {
background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat;
height:50px;
width:50px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer works! Thank you. Just a small doubt. How do I get a the full image to be displayed within the mentioned size?

Comment: @dishoom use  background-size: cover;

Comment: @SathishS: background-size: cover; doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @dishoom try this... background-size: contain;

Answer (score 1):

Your #header is 0px x 0px big. Give it a size (width and height) and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

you forget to set height and width.,

```
#header{
    background-image: url('bg.jpg');
     background-size: cover;
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px;
     border: 0px;
     width:100%;/* what size you need to add here */
     heigth:50%;
}
```

Comment: Still no luck. When I call it on div, the page is blank. Any help @Sathish S?

Comment: @Sathish S - you need to give some height.

Comment: @SagarRaj: I gave the height. I've edited my question adding my code. Still no luck. :-(

Comment: @dishoom - dude check my answer. Also check your image path. And accept my answer if it worked.

Comment: #header {
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url("bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 0 none;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

use this if you see a background color in your screen, then please check your image path !!

Answer (score 0):

Its because of Height and Width. Specify height and width.

**height: auto;
width: 100%;**

and also indicate **no-repeat**.

Answer (score 0):

please give the height like

```
#header{height: 100px;}
```